# Raw data reanalysis of multiple studies consider as meta analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis

I am struggling with the question of  how to define my research.
I download raw data (RNA sequencing data) from multiple studies and I am going to analyze again them together as they " brought from one study".
Can I call it a meta analysis of some kind?

Thanks a lot!

Ed

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking about doing an 'individual participant/patient data meta-analysis' (IPDMA). It's a bit more involved though than just combining some datasets and pretending they are one large study. To start, you need to respect the multilevel nature of the data. For a very thorough coverage of the topic, see:

Riley, R. D., Tierney, J. F., Stewart, L. A. (Eds) (2021). *Individual participant data meta-analysis: A handbook for healthcare research*. Wiley. https://www.wiley.com/en-am/Individual+Participant+Data+Meta+Analysis:+A+Handbook+for+Healthcare+Research-p-9781119333722

Comment: Great thank you!

Comment: Great thank you! that what I thought. I read the paper PMID: 20139215 says "The statistical implementation of an individual participant data meta-analysis crucially must preserve the clustering of patients within studies; it is inappropriate to simply analyse individual participant data as if they all came from a single study. Clusters can be retained during analysis by using a two step or a one step approach..." made me think it meant something else. but now I understand that I need to read more about the statistical methods...Thanks again for lighting it up:)
Ed.